# setting the build directory in Circle CI

Tags: circleci, circleci-2.0

For come reason I am not able to change my directory when build my pipeline in with Circle CI.

Also the command make is missing in Circle CI :(

file...

```
# Use the latest 2.1 version of CircleCI pipeline process engine.
# See: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference
version: 2.1

# Define a job to be invoked later in a workflow.
# See: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#jobs
jobs:
  api:
    working_directory: ~/api
    docker:
      - image: golang:1.19.3-alpine3.16
    steps:
        - checkout:
              path: ~/api
        -   setup_remote_docker: # (2)
                docker_layer_caching: true # (3)

        # specify any bash command here prefixed with `run: `
        -   run: pwd
        -   run: ls -all
        #-   run: make mod-vendor
        -   run: go get -v -t -d ./...
        -   run: go test -v ./...
        -   run: go build -o main .
        -   deploy:
                command: |
                    if [ "${CIRCLE_BRANCH}" == "circle-ci-setup" ]; then
                      docker build -t ${DOCKER_REPO} .
                      docker login -u ${DOCKER_USER} -p ${DOCKER_PASS} https://index.docker.io/v1/
                      docker push ${DOCKER_REPO}
                    fi
  client:
    working_directory: ~/client
    # Specify the execution environment. You can specify an image from Dockerhub or use one of our Convenience Images from CircleCI's Developer Hub.
    # See: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#docker-machine-macos-windows-executor
    docker:
      - image: cimg/node:16.1.0
      #- image: nginx:1.21.3-alpine
    # Add steps to the job
    # See: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#steps
    steps:
        - checkout:
              path: ~/client
        #- restore_cache:
         #     name: Restore Yarn Package Cache
         #     keys:
         #         - yarn-packages-{{ checksum "yarn.lock" }}
        -   run: pwd
        -   run: ls -all
        - run:
              name: Install Dependencies
              command: yarn install --immutable
        - save_cache:
              name: Save Yarn Package Cache
              key: yarn-packages-{{ checksum "yarn.lock" }}
              paths:
                  - .yarn/cache
                  - .yarn/unplugged
        - run:
                name: Installing the package.json dependencies
                command: yarn

        # run build!
        #-   run: make build-client
        - run: yarn build
        -   persist_to_workspace:
                root: .
                paths: dist

# Invoke jobs via workflows
# See: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#workflows
workflows:
  hobby-project-setup:
    jobs:
      - client
      - api
```

The client part produces an error that reads

```
yarn run v1.22.10
error Couldn't find a package.json file in "/home/circleci/client"
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Exited with code exit status 1
CircleCI received exit code 1
```

and the api

```
#!/bin/sh -eo pipefail
cd api && go get -v -t -d ./...
go: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory.
    'go get' is no longer supported outside a module.
    To build and install a command, use 'go install' with a version,
    like 'go install example.com/cmd@latest'
    For more information, see https://golang.org/doc/go-get-install-deprecation
    or run 'go help get' or 'go help install'.

Exited with code exit status 1
```

ls-all

```
#!/bin/sh -eo pipefail
ls -all
total 32
drwxr-xr-x    7 root     root          4096 Dec  4 12:12 .
drwx------    1 root     root            33 Dec  4 12:12 ..
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root            24 Dec  4 12:12 .circleci
drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root            72 Dec  4 12:12 .git
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            13 Dec  4 12:12 .gitignore
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1369 Dec  4 12:12 Makefile
drwxr-xr-x    6 root     root            95 Dec  4 12:12 api
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          5302 Dec  4 12:12 api.swagger.json
drwxr-xr-x    5 root     root          4096 Dec  4 12:12 client
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           424 Dec  4 12:12 digital-ocean-infra-config.sh
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           263 Dec  4 12:12 docker-compose.yml
drwxr-xr-x    6 root     root           104 Dec  4 12:12 infra
```

This is the same output for client and api...

and pwd for api

```
#!/bin/sh -eo pipefail
pwd
/root/api
CircleCI received exit code 0
```

and pwd for client

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
pwd
/home/circleci/client
CircleCI received exit code 0
```

Doing `cd client && yarn` or `cd api && go build` does work but this cannot be the correct way.

How can I set my working directory for each job?

Answer (score 0):

Though there are a few mistakes in your pipeline, your eventual conclusion to `cd` into the subfolder and execute the required command appears to be the correct one from my testing. The current folder cannot be changed the way you want using `working_directory: ~/api`, because the `checkout` step, that downloads the code, happens after the working directory is set and the `checkout.path` is interpreted as relative to the working directory as per the [docs](https://circleci.com/docs/configuration-reference/#checkout), not as an absolute path like `~/api`. So with the working directory as `~/api` and a checkout step without `path`, your code will be cloned to `~/api`. But at that point the folder you want to execute the `go build` command from would be `~/api/api`, so you'll still need to run `cd api` first. Similarly if you had used the relative path `api` in `checkout.path` with the working directory as `~/api`, the code would have been cloned to `~/api/api`, so now you'd have to `cd api/api` before running the build.

These can be illustrated with the outputs from the below test pipeline:

```yaml
version: 2.1
jobs:
  test:
    docker:
      - image: golang:1.19.3-alpine3.16
        auth:
          username: $DOCKER_USERNAME
          password: $DOCKER_PASSWORD
    resource_class: small
    working_directory: ~/test
    steps:
      - checkout:
          path: app
      - run: pwd
      - run: ls -all
      - run: cd app && ls -all

workflows:
  version: 2.1
  pr_check:
    jobs:
      - test:
          context:
            - docker-credentials
          filters:
            branches:
              only: circleci
```

**Output of pwd step:** (Prints the working directory `/root/test`)

```
#!/bin/sh -eo pipefail
pwd

/root/test

CircleCI received exit code 0
```

**Output of ls step:** (Shows the subfolder `app`)

```
#!/bin/sh -eo pipefail
ls -all

total 4
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root            17 Jun 11 01:29 .
drwx------    1 root     root            30 Jun 11 01:29 ..
drwxr-xr-x    6 root     root          4096 Jun 11 01:29 app

CircleCI received exit code 0
```

**Output of cd & ls:** (Shows the code cloned inside `/root/test/app`)

```
#!/bin/sh -eo pipefail
cd app && ls -all

total 40
drwxr-xr-x    6 root     root          4096 Jun 11 01:29 .
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root            17 Jun 11 01:29 ..
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root            24 Jun 11 01:29 .circleci
drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root            72 Jun 11 01:29 .git
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           154 Jun 11 01:29 .gitattributes
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           154 Jun 11 01:29 .gitignore
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1068 Jun 11 01:29 LICENSE
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            44 Jun 11 01:29 README.md
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1058 Jun 11 01:29 build.gradle
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root            21 Jun 11 01:29 gradle
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          8070 Jun 11 01:29 gradlew
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          2674 Jun 11 01:29 gradlew.bat
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            72 Jun 11 01:29 lombok.config
drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root            30 Jun 11 01:29 src

CircleCI received exit code 0
```

Also the `make` command not being present is not a CircleCI limitation. When you use a `docker` executor with CircleCI, you are limited to the commands that are present in that docker image. In this case, the image `golang:1.19.3-alpine3.16` does not contain `make`. I confirmed that by running `docker run --rm golang:1.19.3-alpine3.16 make` from my local machine which returned the below error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "make": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
```

If a go image with `make` is what you need, CircleCI does provide its own [convenience images](https://circleci.com/developer/images/image/cimg/go) for go. The CircleCI image for go `1.19.3` would be `cimg/go:1.19.3`, which does contain `make`.